# Perforce: How do I p4 integrate a local uncommitted changelist?

Tags: perforce

Here's my scenario:

I have two projects projectA and projectB. A branchspec auto-integrates projectA to projectB.
Now, I have a changelist which modifies some files in projectA -- I have not committed/submitted this changelist yet.

I'd like this changelist to go into projectB only.

Doing a 
p4 integrate -b branchspec -c changelistNumber

shows

"All revision(s) are integrated."

How can I integrate an uncommitted changelist?

Comment: This is an obvious thing to want to do. Why does Perforce make it so painful?

Comment: "asked 5 years ago, viewed 14087 times." Perforce would do well to study these forums to see what users want to do with their software and where it falls short.  Here's a link to most viewed questions  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bperforce%5d%20views%3a2500

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Perforce has a much easier way of accomplishing this:

1. Shelve your changelist on branchA (note the changelist #, we'll call it NUM for reference here)
2. Create a branch mapping between branchA and branchB (we'll call it A_to_B)
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   p4 unshelve -s NUM -b A_to_B
   ```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not available in older versions of perforce.

Comment: Tremendous time saver without having to submit first, which was critical for me.

Comment: Could you explain how to do step 2?

Comment: Go to File>New>Branch Mapping..., give it a name and set up the mapping in the "View" section. For example, to create a mapping from branchA to branchB, you might use the following view:

 //depot/branchA/... //depot/branchB/...

Comment: Please note that you can also do this from the visual client directly. You just need to create a new empty pending change list first.

Comment: To elaborate on @4thex comment above, To do it from the visual client, you need to be connected to the workspace that has the destination mapped, then on the Pending Changelist view, set the filter to the workspace that has the source mapped, and you should see the shelved files. Here you can just right-click, and select Unshelf, which will have the Map unshelved files option.

Answer (score 12):

Hack-ish solution:

1. Check out the files in project B
2. Manually copy files from project A to project B (they're not write-protected due to step 1)
3. Shelve changelist in project A
4. Submit to B
5. Integrate files from B to A and resolve
6. Unshelve files from step 3. Resolve as needed accepting yours.
7. Submit to A when ready

Another approach is to create a separate branch where you do your work and then integ to A or B as needed.

The general idea is that Perforce works in terms of submitted or shelved changelists. The idea of integrating an non-committed changelist seems to go against Perforce's natural grain which makes these workarounds cumbersome.

Comment: "The general idea is that Perforce works in terms of submitted or shelved changelists". I'll remember that :)

Comment: "The general idea is that Perforce works..." Optimistic.

Answer (score 5):

```
p4 diff -u your/branch/... | patch -p x -d your/otherbranch
```

Where x is an int, you should try from 0 until it's working, use --dry-run in patch to test. (-p is the number of directory to strip so that file path in your/branch and your/otherbranch matches, 2 in this example)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the output of p4 diff is not understood by most patch implementation.  You can write code to tweak  the output to something patch will accept though.

Answer (score 3):

I just bumped into the same situation, here is my solution for it (very similar to Jeff's but there is no Submit in the process), maybe it will help someone someday:

1. Integrate (and resolve) the related files from ProjectB to ProjectA while the edited but non-submitted files are there.
2. Check-out the related files in ProjectB.
3. Manually copy the related files from ProjectA to ProjectB.
4. Revert files in ProjectA.

Comment: hi, in step 1, how to Integrate the non-submitted file from B to A?

Answer (score 1):

Knocked up a quick powershell 2 script to do this:

https://gist.github.com/1173044

```
param([int]$changelistNum, [string]$destBranch)
$regex = "^\s+//[^/]+(/\S+)\s"
$sourceFiles = p4 change -o $changelistNum | select-string $regex | %{$_.matches[0]}

$sourceFiles | %{
    $sourcePath = (p4 where $_.groups[0].value.trim()).split(' ')[2];
    $destPath = (p4 where ($destBranch + $_.groups[1].value)).split(' ')[2];
    p4 edit $destPath;
    copy $sourcePath $destPath;
    p4 add $destPath;
}
```

(not sure why indentation not working above - I've prefixed the inside of the script block by 8 spaces?)

The script pulls all files out of the changelist description, and for each one tries to find the corresponding path in the other branch. It brute-forces both a p4 edit for each file and a p4 add, rather than try to guess which one is right. It's quite verbose!

To copy changelist 443 to branch myBranch:

```
Copy-PendingChangelistToBranch.ps1 443 "//myBranch"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [P4_Shelve](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4_Shelve) to move the changes to a new branch which you could then integrate to projectB.

Comment: How do you do that? How do you unshelve in a different branch?

Comment: I didn't mean the main p4 client shelve command, but the older P4_Shelve code I linked to, which does precisely putting the pending changelist on another branch, and reverting it on the original.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach in P4V:

1. On source workspace create shelve of files you want to integrate into another branch, note the CL shelve number - we will use it later
2. On target workspace hit Ctrl + G, type in remembered CL shelve number and accept
3. Select all files (Ctrl + A) in Shelved files section
4. Use Unshelve button from Shelved files section
5. In next window you can set mapping and changelist into which you will unshelve those files - after inspecting click Unshelve

As a result you have new CL with files from shelve that you have to resolve now.