# Perforce method for moving unsubmitted changes to another branch on Windows

Tags: windows, branch, perforce, branching-and-merging

Does anybody have a good way to move pending changes from one branch to another in Perforce (p4d version 2010.2)?

I have a changelist that has pending changes to one branch (eg, //depot/ProjectA_classic/...), but I want to apply those changes to another branch (eg, //depot/ProjectA_newstuff/...) because I've realized I do not want to submit the changes to where I have them pending because the branch has been frozen, but I do want to submit them to a new branch.

Comment: My current method feels very brittle, and messes about with p4 diff -du, a version of patch for windows that I dug up, and some monkeying with a sed script to checkout the matching files before patching.  I'm pretty sure it'll fall apart if my pending change deletes or adds a file.

Comment: Recent versions of Perforce allow you to unshelve a shelved changelist on a different branch, which would be ideal for your use case, but I don't think that will work with 2010.2

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question, I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472541/perforce-how-do-i-p4-integrate-a-local-uncommited-changelist/

Comment: Shelves have been around since 2009.2. However, unshelving through a branch spec was indeed a more recent feature (2013.1). Perhaps you can upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Ganesh's comment above, you need to create a branch mapping from //depot/ProjectA_classic/... to  //depot/ProjectA_newstuff/... using a recent version of p4v.  I am using 2014.3 here.

Then you shelve the files and unshelve them using the branch mapping option in the unshelve dialog.

[image: Unshelved using branch mapping option]